# Shell script for jar file

Tags: java, linux, shell, jar, spring-boot

I have an application based on Spring Boot that have structure like this:

```
|-- src
|   |-- main
|      |-- java
|         |-- api
|         |-- core
|   |-- resources
|-- public
|   |--en
|   `pom.xml
```

When I build it with maven I have a single jar file and a public folder with html files. I tried to make a shell script that starts a web server and add it to the $PATH

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar /path-to-jar/myapp.jar $1
```

But when I start it from any folder that isn't `/path-to-jar/` server crashes because can't find `public` folder.

Is it possible to make a script that will refer to that folder in `/path-to-jar/` and not in current path?

Comment: The simplest can be:
(cd /your/folder && java -jar /path-to-jar/myapp.jar $1)
It runs the process in a subshell.

Comment: Sometimes we don't think about simplest way :) Thank you, @Samar , it's working perfectly! :)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its working for you, I am putting it as an answer. The simplest can be: `(cd /your/folder && java -jar /path-to-jar/myapp.jar $1)`

It runs the process in a subshell. If its just the line in your bash script, you can omit the small braces. The reason I kept braces is to avoid changing of directory in case you source the file but I believe you simply need a simple script to get your job done.